# How do I modify the data type from MySQL column in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to modify the data type for the column 'observacion' (seventh row in the first image) from VARCHAR to TEXT with the following code:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql ='''ALTER TABLE requerimientos    
MODIFY observacion TEXT'''
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```

[image]

But I am getting the following error: "DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'fecha' at row 6", You can see in the bottom right of the next image the "Incorrect Value" that is causing the error. The problem is that the error corresponds to another column and it is not the one that I am trying to modify.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this structure:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Comment: It did not work, got the following error: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEXT' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing all the NULL values in the column 'fecha' (which is the one that was causing me trouble) with a date, then I was able to change the datatype of the column 'observacion' as I initially intended